# Declaring a single image from a sprite sheet in javascript

Tags: javascript, sprite

I'm trying to define and declare an image from a sprite sheet in javascript.
I've defined the image within an external style sheet as follows:

```css
#myimage{ background-position: 0 -751px; width: 21px; height: 21px; }

.dwg { background:url(spriteSheet.png) no-repeat;}
```

I've tried various arrangements similar to the following, none of which, of course, works.

```
myimage=new Image();
myimage.src="background:url('spriteSheet.png') 0 0; width: 35px; height: 16px;  no-repeat";
```

I use the image as follows:

```js
document.stat.src = myimage.src;
```

My Javascript conditional logic switches between various images depending upon status.  The code has worked fine with individual images, but I have combined them into a sprite sheet and now need to assign individual images from the sheet.  And in order to do so, I need to define each image as a JavaScript variable.

What should be inserted in place of the `background: url...` string?

Answer (score 1):

A few months I a started using the following approach and it became the easiest to me:

JS code:

```
    $('[class*=sprite-]').each(function(){
        var crr = this.className.match(/sprite\-(\d+)\-(\d+)/);
        if ( crr && crr[2]) {
            $(this).css('background-position', '-'+ crr[1] +'px -'+ crr[2] +'px');
            $(this).addClass('sprite');
        }
    });
```

CSS code:

```
.sprite {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(your-sprite-image.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML code (You may replace "50x50" by your sprite coordinate):

```
<img class="sprite-50-50" width="100" height="200" src="use-a-blank-image.gif" alt="" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do because the code is a little weird.  The `src` attribute is the `src` of the image.  If you are doing a sprite... then you should probably be using a div tag, not even using an img.  Sprites are usually not "img" tags, but usually "div" tags that are formatted to show just a single frame of your sprite sheet using a background-image.  You would only need to adjust the background properties of the div using `backgroundImage` and `backgroundPosition` properties and show the sprite you have created.  There is no reason to create an Image object in javascript and try to apply it to your code.

Comment: I edited the original question with a litle more explanation. Bacically, I am just trying to figure out how to name an individual image from a sprite sheet in the form of: document.xxx.src = image.src. OR image.src= . It works fine with individual images but I'm having a difficult time transistioning to sprite sheets.